# What is the main purpose of using Boolean Circuit Model in Homomorphic Encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Why do we use or have Boolean Circuit Model is it because since it uses gates and bits we could adapt it into a hardware model?

Comment: Could you not think simple reasoning? We consider building FHE circuit $\mathcal{C}$ with this model. It is not exactly the Hardware Nand model.

Comment: Compared to which alternative?

Comment: Compare to using Modular Arithmetic and Approximate Number i guess?

Comment: Some things you may need to look up, is what are the alternative models and it should answer your question. Try looking into computational complexity first